# How to retrieve all hash values from a list in Redis?

Tags: redis

In Redis, to store an array of objects we should use hash for the object and add its key to a list:

```
HMSET concept:unique_id name "concept"
...
LPUSH concepts concept:unique_id
...
```

I want to retrieve all hash values (or objects) in the list, but the list contains only hash keys so a two step command is necessary, right? This is how I'm doing in python:

```
def get_concepts():

    list = r.lrange("concepts", 0, -1)
    pipe = r.pipeline()

    for key in list:
         pipe.hgetall(key)
    pipe.execute()
```

Is it necessary to iterate and fetch each individual item? Can it be more optimized?

Comment: You could also store all objects in a list (in serialized form. JSON, for example). Then a simple LRANGE will do.

Comment: Thanks Sergio, I haven't thought about that but I would prefer having the possibility of manipulating object's properties in Redis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [SORT](http://redis.io/commands/sort) command to do this:

```
SORT concepts BY nosort GET concept:*->name GET concept:*->some_key
```

Where `*` will expand to each item in the list.

Add `LIMIT offset count` for pagination.

Note that you have to enumerate each field in the hash (each field you want to fetch).

Another option is to use the new (in redis 2.6) [EVAL](http://redis.io/commands/eval) command to execute a Lua script in the redis server, which could do what you are suggesting, but server side.

Comment: what if one of attributes of the object is a list? e.g. LPUSH concept:1:things rabbit . how to get this list instead?

Comment: You can't. Only things which you could otherwise `GET` or `HGET`. See the documentation (linked above -- redis commands generally have really good docs).